# how to compare user input with multiple directories from json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file "contacts.json" containing this :

```
{
"Lisa": {
    "birthday": "09-02-1990"
},
"Marge": {
    "birthday": "05-01-2010"
},
"Bart": {
    "birthday": "23-09-1935"
},
"Homer": {
    "birthday": "22-11-1990"
}
}
```

Now I need to write a code to extract the birthday of the input name that user inputs.
I wrote this code but its not working

```
import json

name = input('Enter name of the person you want to see his/her birthday ')

with open('contacts.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for i in data[i]:
    if name == data[i]:
        print(data[i]['Birthday'])

    else:
        print('Person not found')

file.close()
```

Comment: For a good question the json code should also be formated and "its not working import json" should be specified more precisely (e.g. error message).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
import json

name = input('Enter name of the person you want to see his/her birthday ')

with open('contacts.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

birthday = ''

for value in data:
    if name == value:
        birthday = data[value]['birthday']
        break
    else:
        birthday = 'Person not found'

print(birthday)

file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not fullfilling my requiremnet. for example If I give "Lisa" as input it should display Lisa's birthday and if my input name is not in the jason file then it will display person not found

Comment: That's exactly what it is doing. Did you try to run the code above?

Comment: somehow in my case its always showing "Person not found"

Comment: If you see in If statment where we are checking name == value , In every case It will false because we are giving name 'Lisa' as input.

Comment: @SanaRasheed could you please print the "data" variable and post the output here? I tried the code with the json you posted in the question and it's working here. maybe as you said, is a problem on reading the json.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```py
arr = { "Lisa": { "birthday": "09-02-1990" }, "Marge": { "birthday": "05-01-2010" }, "Bart": { "birthday": "23-09-1935" }, "Homer": { "birthday": "22-11-1990" } }

name = "lisa"

bs = "Person not found"
for k, v in arr.items():
    if name.lower() in k.lower():
        bs = "{0}'s birthday: {1}".format(k, v.get('birthday'))
        break
print(bs)
```

Note: For Python 2.x use arr.iteritems() instead of arr.items()

Comment: Thanks I have used .item() function and now my code is working